# How do I test validations in Rubymine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Im new to learning Rails and am using Rubymine. Im going through the book RailsSpace and have a question. We created a user model and then created all these validations for when we create new users and it now says to test our validations... However I am not quite sure how to do that. It shows me the code but **Im not sure where in *Rubymine* I can go to test the user validations** we made. Help :)

Here's the code it shows the book. From what I understand I need to try and create a new user and give it a username, email, and password... And then it's giving errors on the validations. But where do I create this new user and enter the username, password, and email?

```
>> reload!

>> user = User.new( :screen_name => "me",

?>                  :password => "a"

?>                  :email => " ")

=> #<User: 0xb76fad0 @new_record=true,
  @attributes={"screen_name"=>"me", "password"=>"a", "email"=>""}>

>> user.save

=> false

>> user.errors.on(:screen_name)

=>["is to short (minimum is 4 charaters)", "has already been taken"]
```

Thanks!
C

Comment: In addition to my answer, I suggest you look up how to format your questions and answers in markdown, which will make them easier to read. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the RuyMine interface, there's a terminal icon:

[image]

Here I've opened RubyMine's built-in terminal and started `rails console`. I'm using a model called `Line` that has 3 validations for presence. I've called `new` on it, without passing in any attributes as parameters. The `valid?` method runs the validations without saving my new object. Since I haven't given it the attributes it requires, it is not valid. To see why the validations failed, I call `errors.full_messages`. It shows the three required attributes that are missing.

[image]

So, to create a valid `Line` object, I need to give it the three required attributes as parameters to `new`. It will now pass its validations:

[image]

Comment: At this point, I could successfully call `save`, but I don't want to add this made-up line to the development database I use for work :)